# no access to GetCaptureProperty or any similar function in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I tried lot of combinations in opencv 2.3 and 2.4 to get frame count of a video, but without any result. It seems it simply isn't there.

```
stream = cv.VideoCapture(avsfilename) #stream.isOpened() returns True, everything's ok
framecount = cv.GetCaptureProperty(stream, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) #no
framecount = cv.GetCaptureProperty(stream, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) #no
framecount = stream.get(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) #no
framecount = stream.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) #no
```

'module' object has no attribute 'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT'

Anyone passed something similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got to be a little careful of your `cv2` and `cv` imports, both of these work:

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv

#Using cv2:
stream = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
print stream.get(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)

#using cv:
stream = cv.CaptureFromFile(filename)
print cv.GetCaptureProperty(stream, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
```

Comment: You were right. It's littlebit confusing for first time, but this is it.

Comment: Is there documentation on how to "port" an app that uses the cv style APIs to the cv2 style?

The import cv2.cv as cv no longer works and thus the code I have that uses cv doesn't work and will need to change it from what I see here.